# mysql substring_index reverse

Tags: mysql, string

in MYSQL, given a string with dots in it, I want to select everything before the last dot.  for example:
input

```
www.java2s.com
```

output:

```
www.java2s
```

substring_index seems to do the opposite:

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.java2s.com', '.', -1);
+--------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.java2s.com', '.', -1) |
+--------------------------------------------+
| com                                        |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    select substr('www.java2s.sth.com', 1, (length('www.java2s.sth.com')- 
    length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(('www.java2s.sth.com'), '.', -1))-1));`
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a nicer solution here it is:

```
SET @domain = "www.java2s.com";
SELECT SUBSTRING(@domain, 1, LENGTH(@domain)-LOCATE('.', REVERSE(@domain)));
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.java2s.com', '.', 2)
```

more generic

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.java2s.com', '.', ( LENGTH('www.java2s.com') - LENGTH(REPLACE('www.java2s.com', '.', '')))  )
```

Comment: the problem is that I don't know how many dots are in the file, I don't know it's 2 or x